# How to separate words in a sentences string in JavaScript without comma

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to ask how to separate words in a sentences string without commas, when the initial letter is capitalized from the previous letter then the word is separated

```
example 
let str = "WishYourLuck"

//expected output = Wish Your Luck
```

**thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace using regexp that captures word ends `/([a-z])([A-Z])/g` ie small letter followed by capital letter.

```js
let str = "WishYourLuck"

console.log(str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, (_, a, b) => `${a} ${b}`))
```

W/o `replace`

```js
let str = "WishYourLuck"

console.log(splitWords(str))


function splitWords(str) {
  const out = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const char = str[i]
    const prevChar = str[i-1]
    if (i && char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' && prevChar >= 'a' && prevChar <= 'z') {
      out.push(' ')
    }
    
    out.push(char)
  }
  
  return out.join('')
}
```

Comment: is it possible without using built-in functions like str.replace ?

Comment: Yes, loop over the string and find when current symbol is uppercase while previous is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

A little too late. Here is how to do it step by step.

```js
const str = "WishYourLuck";
const arr = [...str];
let res = '';

arr.forEach((c) => {
  if (c == c.toLowerCase()) {        
    res += c; // The character is lowercase
  } else {
    res += ' ' + c; // The character is uppercase
  }  
})

console.log(res)
```